# How to solve this recursion problem(Javascript)

Tags: javascript, recursion

How do you write the above code to achieve my expected results, please help me give some pointers

```js
let apis = {
  home: {
    index: {
      url: '/index',
      auth: false
    },
    tab: {
      url: '/tab',
      auth: true
    }
  },
  test: {
    test: {
      url: '/test',
      auth: false
    }
  }
}

let getItem = function (obj){
  for(let item in obj){
    if(obj.url === '/test') return
    if(obj[item] instanceof Object)
      getItem(obj[item])
  }
  return obj
}
console.log(getItem(apis))
```

Expected results:

```json
{
   url: '/test',
   auth: false
}
```

I am doing this now, but it cannot achieve the expected effect

#### :) Thinks

Comment: `it cannot achieve the expected effect` is a useless description of the result ... `it achieves the following result ...` is a very useful description of the result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const apis = {
  home: {
    index: {
      url: '/index',
      auth: false
    },
    tab: {
      url: '/tab',
      auth: true
    }
  },
  test: {
    test: {
      url: '/test',
      auth: false
    }
  }
}

const getItem = (obj) => {
  if (obj.url === '/test') {
    return obj
  }
  for (let item in obj) {
    if (obj[item] instanceof Object) {
      const result = getItem(obj[item])
      if (result.url === '/test') {
        return result
      }
    }
  }
  return {};
}

console.log(getItem(apis))
```

Comment: Think you very much